# The result of Dynamic_reconfigure tutorial not update

Tags: ros, tutorial, ros-kinetic, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have studied dynamic reconfigure to use it with my project. I had followed the tutorial until http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/UsingTheDynamicReconfigurePythonClient. However, after I ran both server.py and client.py, they did not show the same results which is different to what tutorial say. The terminal that I run client.py did not print anything and for server.py terminal print once and not update anything. And after I ctr+C to exist the client.py it give me these msgs which I really confuse about it.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/beerlablinux/catkin_ws/src/dynamic_tutorials/nodes/client.py", line 15, in

rospy.wait_for_service("dynamic_tutorials")

File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 159, in wait_for_service

raise ROSInterruptException("rospy shutdown")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: rospy shutdown

I try to find out the solution in Q&A and follow this http://answers.ros.org/question/217402/request-update-in-dynamic-reconfigure-tutorial/ but it still be the same.

Sorry for my English and please help me.

I use ROS kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261675/the-result-of-dynamic_reconfigure-tutorial-not-update/) by [p.beerzzzzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/30372/p.beerzzzzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just found the solution.
In server.py, line 14

```
 rospy.init_node("dynamic_tutorials", anonymous = True)
```

I have changed anonymous = False. And in  client.py, line 15

```
  rospy.wait_for_service("dynamic_tutorials")
```

I have change "dynamic_tutorials" to "dynamic_tutorials/set_parameters"

Everything work!!

---

Originally posted by [p.beerzzzzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/30372/p.beerzzzzz/) with karma: 16 on 2017-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0